# Existence of homogeneous nonzero divisors?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose that $M$ is a graded ring over $R$. Let $P$ be the maximal homogeneous proper ideal in $R$. If there is an $f \in P$ which is a nonzero divisor for $M$ ($fm = 0$ implies $m = 0$), but $f$ is not necessarily homogeneous, is there a choice of homogeneous $g \in P$ which is not a zero divisor for $M$?

(More generally, I am wondering about the notion of depth - is it the same to require a regular sequence of homogeneous elements as it is to require a regular sequence?)

Comment: Try to read the Proposition 1.5.11 from Bruns and Herzog.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the reference, the discussion in that section is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide an answer to my question, just so that it can get closed.

Lemma: (1.5.10 in Bruns and Herzog) $R$ graded and I an ideal generated by elements of positive degree. Let $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ be a finite collection of primes such that $I \not \subset P_i$ for each $i$. Then there is a *homogeneous* element $x \in I$ so that $x \not \in P_1 \cup \ldots \cup P_n$.

(In other words, prime avoidance can be upgraded speak specifically about the existence of a homogeneous element.)

Proof idea: The generated in positive degree assumption means that by taking appropriate exponents, one can get a homogeneous nonzero divisor. Formally, one inducts after making some reductions.

The generated in positive degree assumption is necessary, otherwise the ring $K[x,y]/(xy)$, $\deg(x) = 0$, $\deg(y) = 1$ provides a counterexample: $x + y$ is a nonzero divisor in $(x,y)$, but every homogeneous element in $(x,y)$ is a zero divisor.